# Enter cell text with formula, in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to identify the dates, in filtered rows in column D, from 5 years to present date and return "Append to Audit" in the corresponding row V.

I get

> Compile Error: Expected: end of statement.

```vb
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("V2:V" & Lastrow) = "= IF(D2>= DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-5,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), "Append to Audit", " ")"
```

Have attempted to add and remove spaces in special characters and redefine.

Comment: Double up the `"` inside the formula.